# Capl - simulation of TestWaitForDiagResponse (available for canoe only) through capl in canalyzer

Tags: capl

I am using canalyzer. How to simulate the TestWaitForDiagResponse function of canoe in canalyzer using capl?

Comment: TestWaitForDiagResponse function as far as i know is available only for Canoe. how do i simulate the behaviour of the function in canalyzer through capl

Comment: or is there any equivalent function for canalyzer...This is whether the diagnostic response is obtained within the specified time

Answer (score 1):

You can use `TestWaitForDiagResponse()` function only with the CANalyzer pro or with CANoe. 
 **Please note, Waiting for diagnostic events is only possible in test modules! Conventional CAPL nodes continue to operate, but only by the event-driven principle.**

To call this function you have to create a test module. There are two types of TestWaitForDiagResponse function: 
`1. long TestWaitForDiagResponse (diagRequest request, dword timeout);`
`2. long TestWaitForDiagResponse (dword timeout);`

For the first one you have to declare a diagnostic-object like `DiagRequest ServiceQualifier request;` 
 This function waits exactly for the declared response object with the configured protocol (P2/P2*) timings.
The second function is waiting for any response with the configured protocol (P2/P2*) timings.